# Integration of uniformly convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

From Hassani's *Mathematical Methods for Students of Physics and Related Fields*
pg. 278:

> **Theorem 9.4.3** If $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i(x)$ is uniformly convergent, and each $u_i(x)$ is continuous for $a\leq x\leq b$, then the series can be integrated term by term, i.e.,
> $$\int^b_a f(x) dx = \int^b_a \sum^\infty_{i=1} u_i(x) dx = \sum^\infty_{i=1} \int^b_a u_i(x)dx,$$
> i.e. integration and summation can be interchanged.

Why is this only true for uniformly convergent series? Shouldn't it be true for all series since we have the integration rule
$$\int h(x) + g(x) dx = \int h(x)dx+\int g(x)dx?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration rule holds for only finite sums. It does not say anything about summing infinitely many functions, which happens not to be true in general. For instance if $f_n(x) = n^2x(1-x^2)^n$, and we define $g_1 = f_1$ and $g_n = f_{n} - f_{n-1}$, we see that for $0\le x \le 1$,
$$
\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 0 \ \mathrm{d}x = 0
$$
whereas
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1 g(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_0^1 g(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{N\to\infty} \int f_N(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N^2}{2N+1} = +\infty.
$$